# Facebook graph api get user IM

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is there any way to get the IM username in contact information, for example jabber or msn username? I didnt find the apropirate permission in api docs. Have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply: You can't access that information via graph API.